# Invalid base64 string and base64 compression

Tags: javascript, c#, canvas, base64

I am using canvas.todataURL() to get base64 string but when I am using that string in webAPI based on C# it says invalid string. I have excluded the header "data:image/jpg;base64" and also its length is in multiple of 4.

Hence I am unable to figure out why it is saying it contains non base64 or more than 2 padding characters.

1. How to make this string standard base64
2. When I copy Google images base64 it is shorter for same size images. Is there any way to compress base64 strings.\

Sample string is here:

```js
var sampleBase64= '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…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';
```

I am using it as:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64); //gives error
```

Comment: Could you provide us with an example of an invalid string and how you're using it? Without that information it's impossible to say for certain what's going wrong. At best, we can make educated guesses.

Comment: @MikeC Revised it!

Comment: You've got a non-ASCII character '…' in your `sampleBase64` which is not allowed.